# Personal Campaign Page image is not showing

Tags: personal-campaign-pages, images, pcp

Drupal: 7.59
 CiviCRM 5.3.2

Using PCP for the first time. When the user uploads an image it is showing only when the user is logged in to CiviCRM. The image is not showing for the invitees for support for the PCP. If I try to access the image from the developer tools in IE, I get access denied.
Any help would be appreciated as my event goes live in a few weeks

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably you will need to give 'CiviCRM: access uploaded files' for anonymous user. But this is dangerous to provide access to files for anonymous user.

Comment: Where are the PCP image files uploaded too?

Comment: I found the file at sites/default/files/civicrm/sari/custom/ 
The permissions were correct at 644 and 755 for file and directory respectively.  The page with the issue is at http://sari.ca/civicrm/pcp/info?reset=1&id=1 Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Also I attempted to give the access you suggested and I am not able to even though I am signed in with admin access. Is there an over-ride that prevents that?

Comment: I found that the anonymous user was locked to I had to  make the permission change at the role level. And now the file is uploaded file is viewable. Thanks